# Amino spam bot gives an error on login (python)

Tags: python, bots

I'm not good at programming, so I took the code from the github, but after entering the password and email, an error pops up

Code

```
import amino
import asyncio
import pyfiglet
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style
init()
print(Fore.CYAN)
print("""Script by Lil Zevi
Github : https://github.com/LilZevi""")
print(pyfiglet.figlet_format("aminowallspam", font="stop"))

async def main():
    client = amino.Client()
    email = input("Email >> ")
    password = input("Password >> ")
    await client.login(email=email, password=password)
    clients = await client.sub_clients(start=0, size=100)
    for x, name in enumerate(clients.name, 1):
        print(f"{x}.{name}")
    communityid = clients.comId[int(input("Select the community >> "))-1]
    sub_client = await amino.SubClient(comId=communityid, profile=client.profile)
    userlink = input("User Link >> ")
    user_info = await client.get_from_code(userlink)
    userId = user_info.objectId
    comment = input("Message >> ")
    while True:
        try:
            await sub_client.comment(message=comment, userId=userId)
            print("WallComment Sended")
        except:
            pass

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\py\am\am.py", line 32, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:\py\am\am.py", line 15, in main
    await client.login(email=email, password=password)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\client.py", line 210, in login
    if response.status != 200: return exceptions.CheckException(json.loads(await response.text()))
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\amino\lib\util\exceptions.py", line 855, in CheckException
    elif api_code == 103 or api_code == 104: raise InvalidRequest(data)
amino.lib.util.exceptions.InvalidRequest: {'api:duration': '0.009s', 'api:message': 'Invalid Request. Please update to the latest version. If the problem continues, please contact us.', 'api:timestamp': '2021-08-23T13:27:25Z', 'api:statuscode': 104}
```

Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000288650D4910>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x00000288650D78E0>, 456619.406)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x00000288650D4940>

Comment: So... have you updated `amino` to the latest version like the error suggests? If you already have, did you contact the developers?

Comment: @MattDMo I installed amino.py, but I don't have the application itself. I will install now

Comment: @MattDMo It turns out Amino cannot be downloaded on pc

Comment: Have you tried to debbug, search for the error in the web? What have you tried?